# Total count of all the tokens

Tags: elasticsearch

Is it possible to get the `ttf` (total term frequency) for all the tokens from a field in all the shards for a given index?

e.g. I have:

```
PUT /index/type/1
{
  "sentence": "delicious cake"
}

PUT /index/type/2
{
  "sentence": "horrible cake"
}
```

I want to get:

```
cake 2
horrible 1
delicious 1
```

Also is it possible to do it for multiple fields (let's say I'd have `sentence1` and `sentence2` and I'd like to run such a count on the concatenation of them)?

I know [termvectors](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/docs-termvectors.html) give the ttf and that [mtermvectors](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/docs-multi-termvectors.html) can do it for multiple documents but then I'd have to go through all the documents and handle the results myself somehow.

Actually only the top K terms would be sufficient for me if I can control K.

Answer (score 2):

If your field 'sentence' is analyzed you can get TTF with [Terms Facet](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/1.4/search-facets-terms-facet.html):

```
POST /index/type/_search
{
  "query": {
    "match_all": {}
  },
  "facets" : {
      "sentence" : {
          "terms" : {
              "field" : "sentence",
              "size" : 10
          }
    }
  }
}
```

TTF will be in facet part of response

Also you can pass array of fields ["sentence", "sentence2"] to count TTF across multiple fields

```
POST /index/type/_search
{
    "query" : {
        "match_all" : {  }
    },
    "facets" : {
        "multiple_sentence" : {
            "terms" : {
                "fields" : ["sentence", "sentence2"],
                "size" : 10
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: 'size' parameter is actually top K terms

Comment: Since facets [are deprecated and have been removed in 2.0](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/breaking_20_removed_features.html#_facets_have_been_removed), consider using [aggregations](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-aggregations-bucket-terms-aggregation.html) instead. Also note that the `terms` aggregation does not support the `fields` property anymore.

Comment: my bad, I should have mentioned I'm using ES 2.1